# System.EntryPointNotFoundException even after specifying entrypoint (function name) in c# code

Tags: c#, exception

Gone through number of articles and stack overflow link but could not found the solution or might be doing some silly mistake. So posting my code here if any one can help me to resolve the issue. Much appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

**extern.cpp**

```
#define EXPORT extern "C" __declspec( dllexport ) __cdecl FillAndReturnString(char **someString);

#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void _stdcall FillAndReturnString(char **someString)
{
    *someString = (char*)malloc(sizeof(200));
     strcpy_s(*someString, 200, "This is a sample Test");  
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CallingCpp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Zero;

            NativeTest.FillAndReturnString(ref ptr);
            String s = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr);
            Console.WriteLine(s);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    public static class NativeTest
    {
        private const string DllFilePath = @"C:\Test\MemoryTest\MemoryTestApp.dll";

        [DllImport(DllFilePath, EntryPoint = "FillAndReturnString")]
        public static extern void FillAndReturnString(ref IntPtr ptr);
    }
}
```

Some settings I have tried but doesn't work out:

1. Enabled CLR support from cpp project properties.
   Error: Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
   Error   D8016   '/clr' and '/EHs' command-line options are incompatible MemoryTestApp   [project path]
2. Set the calling convention in CPP project properties to __cdecl(/Gd). I have also tried specifying in the file with __stdcall as well.

   [DllImport(DllFilePath, EntryPoint = "FillAndReturnString", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
   public static extern void FillAndReturnString(ref IntPtr ptr);
3. Checked cpp dll with Dependency Walker but it throws an error: At least one required implicit or forwarded dependency was not found.

Comment: This approach is fundamentally flawed in that your unmanaged function allocates a string with `malloc` that your managed code cannot free. A real `FillAndReturnString` function would take an (allocated) buffer and a size. Is this a toy example or do you mean to interop with actual unmanaged code that looks like this?

Comment: Basically I need help to resolve the exception. I tried couple of approaches but negative. On memory allocation part I agree instead of malloc specifying the buffer size parameter to free it or using CoTaskMemAlloc might help to free it using Marshal but I will check on this later. By any chance did you got any mistake in the posted code which causing this exception or anything I am missing?

Comment: The most glaring problem is the do-nothing `#define EXPORT`. To export the function, declare the prototype as `extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall FillAndReturnString(...)`. You can verify what your DLL actually exports from the VS command prompt with `dumpbin /exports`; a correct entry point looks like `_FunctionName@X`, with X the total size of the arguments in bytes. That's only the start of things, though; you'll want to read up on how to do proper string marshaling. `StringBuilder` is much more convenient than manually twiddling pointers.

Comment: To be clear, in the above, I don't mean `...` literally, I was just too lazy to write out the arguments. In most languages this wouldn't be a problem, but in C and C++ this is a legal declaration as a varargs function... but that's not what you want.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen. After making your suggested changes the code works fine. The reason I have to use interop is to free the memory through c# as the project requirement.

Comment: C# cannot correctly free memory allocated with `malloc`, because it has no access to the C runtime used by the unmanaged code. You'd either have to export another function that calls `free()`, or allocate with `HeapAlloc`/`LocalAlloc`/any other mechanism with an exported function to free it. In general, you are better off having the managed size allocate the memory as well.